# VirtualBox - "host-only" with internet

Tags: iptables, virtualbox, virtual-machine, manjaro

Okay friends! I would really appreciate some help this time! =|

I'm using **VirtualBox** virtualizer and I'm trying to make my guest machines have access to the internet using **ONLY** a "host-only" network interface (VirtualBox).

According to the official documentation in https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html using a "host-only" network interface I have the following "network modes" (accesses)...

```
VM  <-> Host     | YES
VM1 <-> VM2      | YES
VM   -> Internet | NO
```

**However**, there are **A LOT** of documentations on the internet that informing you can access the internet (using only the "host-only" interface) from a guest machine using the following "trick"/"workaround" (example) on the host machine...

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -i vboxnet0 -s 192.168.56.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

I tested many and many examples. The `iptables.service` is running correctly on my host machine. **WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?**

My host is a Linux Manjaro (Linux Arch based).

**Thanks a lot!**

Below are some sources with information about the "trick"/"workaround" I mentioned...

> http://archlinux.org.ru/forum/topic/2219/
>   http://nerdbynature.de/s9y/2015/06/09/VirtualBox-switching-to-Host-only-networking
>   https://askubuntu.com/questions/293816/in-virtualbox-how-do-i-set-up-host-only-virtual-machines-that-can-access-the-in
>   https://cuckoo.sh/docs/installation/host/routing.html
>   https://downloads.cuckoosandbox.org/docs/installation/guest/network.html
>   https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo/issues/1376
>   https://jackal777.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/internet-access-in-virtualbox-host-only-networking/
>   https://kyrofa.com/posts/virtualbox-internet-access-with-host-only-network
>   https://precisionsec.com/virtualbox-host-only-network-cuckoo-sandbox-0-4-2/
>   https://superuser.com/questions/1223801/virtualbox-nat-and-host-only-connection/1223853
>   [Virtualbox NAT + Host-Only Adapter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74663/virtualbox-nat-host-only-adapter)
>   https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4922/week-in-geek-the-fixing-slow-internet-in-virtualbox-xp-guest-edition/
>   https://www.rffuste.com/tag/cuckoo/
>   https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Below are some of the **MANY** examples I tested...

```
 > --------------------------------------------
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.56.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
 < --------------------------------------------
 > --------------------------------------------
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i vboxnet0 -s 192.168.56.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
 < --------------------------------------------
 > --------------------------------------------
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -i vboxnet0 -s 192.168.56.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
 < --------------------------------------------
 > --------------------------------------------
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -i vboxnet0 -s 192.168.56.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -j MASQUERADE
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
 < --------------------------------------------
 > --------------------------------------------
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -i vboxnet0 -s 192.168.56.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp=1
 < --------------------------------------------
 > --------------------------------------------
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -o vboxnet0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i vboxnet0 -o <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -j ACCEPT
 < --------------------------------------------
 > --------------------------------------------
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i vboxnet0 -s 192.168.56.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
 < --------------------------------------------
 > --------------------------------------------
sudo bash -c "printf \"net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1\nnet.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 1\n\" >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
sudo sysctl -p
sudo iptables -t filter -I FORWARD --in-interface vboxnet0 --out-interface <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> --source 192.168.56.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t filter -I FORWARD --in-interface <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> --out-interface vboxnet0 --destination 192.168.56.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -j MASQUERADE
 < --------------------------------------------
 > --------------------------------------------
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -o enp+ -t nat -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -o wlp+ -t nat -j MASQUERADE
 < --------------------------------------------
 > --------------------------------------------
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i vboxnet+ -j MARK --set-mark 1
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -o enp+ -t nat -m mark --mark 1 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -o wlp+ -t nat -m mark --mark 1 -j MASQUERADE
 < --------------------------------------------
 > --------------------------------------------
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -s 192.168.56.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.56.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.56.0/24 -d 192.168.56.0/24 -j ACCEPT
 < --------------------------------------------
 > --------------------------------------------
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -i vboxnet0 -s 192.168.56.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.56.0/24 -o <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -i vboxnet0 -j ACCEPT
 < --------------------------------------------
 > --------------------------------------------
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i vboxnet0 -d 192.168.56.0/255.255.255.0 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i vboxnet0 -s 192.168.56.0/255.255.255.0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -d 192.168.56.0/255.255.255.0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -j MASQUERADE
 < --------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why use a host-only network configuration for something that is clearly not host-only?

Comment: @roaima This is a "workaround". It is the only way to have the accesses "VM <-> Host", "VM1 <-> VM2" and "VM -> Internet" using a single network interface. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- INTRODUCTION:

It is a complete guide to have the accesses "VM <-> Host", "VM1 <-> VM2" and "VM -> Internet" on the guests using a single network interface ("host-only") on VirtualBox.

**IMPORTANT:** Run all the commands as "root".

- EXECUTE ON   **H O S T**  :

**NOTE:** We use a Manjaro (Arch based) host as a template. You may need adjustments and changes to other distros.

You need to copy the iptables template configuration file...

```
cp /etc/iptables/empty.rules /etc/iptables/iptables.rules
```

... so you can start the "iptables.service".

Enable and start "iptables.service"...

```
systemctl enable iptables.service
systemctl start iptables.service
```

Enable IP forwarding...

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
printf "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1\n" >> /etc/sysctl.d/30-ipforward.conf
```

Add the following iptables rules. This will forward packets through the host ("vboxnet0") and to the internet...

TEMPLATE I:

```
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD --in-interface vboxnet0 --out-interface <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> --source 192.168.56.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD --in-interface <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> --out-interface vboxnet0 --destination 192.168.56.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o <HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET> -j MASQUERADE
```

... **OR** add the following iptables rules...

TEMPLATE II:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.56.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
```

**NOTE:** On the "TEMPLATE II" you do not need to inform the name of the host interface (`<HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET>`) and the name of the VirtualBox interface (`vboxnet0`). In that way any host interface that has internet will work, that is, I do not have to adjust the name of the interface that has internet whenever it changes. An example of this is when we change from the wired interface (eg .: enp4s0f2) to the wireless interface (eg: wlp3s0) and vice-versa.

**FURTHER QUESTION:** I presented two ways to configure "iptables" because I do not know if there is any advantage in using the "TEMPLATE I". Any comment?

**TIP:** To find out the name of the network interface (`<HOST_INTERFACE_WITH_INTERNET>`) that has internet use the "ip a" command.

Save rules to iptables configuration and restart the service...

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/iptables.rules
systemctl restart iptables.service
```

Enable and start "dnsmasq" in host...

```
systemctl enable dnsmasq.service
systemctl start dnsmasq.service
```

**NOTE:** "dnsmasq" is a small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server.

- EXECUTE ON   **G U E S T**  :

**NOTE:** We use a CentOS 7 guest as a template. You may need adjustments and changes to other distros.

Configure the network interface according to the model...

**NOTE:** The network configuration file is in the "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/" folder path.

```
BOOTPROTO=static
DEVICE=<NETWORK_INTERFACE_NAME>
DNS1=<HOST-ONLY_HOST_IP>
GATEWAY=<HOST-ONLY_HOST_IP>
IPADDR=<HOST-ONLY_GUEST_IP>
IPV6INIT=NO
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=NO
ZONE=
```

Eg.:

```
BOOTPROTO=static
DEVICE=eno16777736
DNS1=192.168.56.1
GATEWAY=192.168.56.1
IPADDR=192.168.56.101
IPV6INIT=NO
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=NO
ZONE=
```

Restart the network service...

```
systemctl restart network.service
```

To test...

```
curl http://www.google.com
```

That's all folks! =D

- REFERENCE:

> https://jackal777.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/internet-access-in-virtualbox-host-only-networking/
>   https://askubuntu.com/questions/293816/in-virtualbox-how-do-i-set-up-host-only-virtual-machines-that-can-access-the-in
>   https://kyrofa.com/posts/virtualbox-internet-access-with-host-only-network
>   http://archlinux.org.ru/forum/topic/2219/
>   https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Iptables
>   https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Internet_sharing

Comment: Works on ubuntu 18 host machine, thank you.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it without dnsmasq? I am using an Android x86 guest.

Comment: If the "dnsmasq" service is turned off, the scheme stops working. Then, no. =D